# Simple Shell script to log disk space

Tags: shell-script

I'm working on automating collecting disk space on a group of servers.

In a standard terminal, if I run:

```
ssh server1 ssh server2 df -h
```

Then I get the output of the command, just fine.

However, if I attempt this method from within a script using a For Loop. Then it fails.

Example Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

GROUP="server1 server2"

for s in $GROUP; do 
    ssh bastion1 ssh ${s} df -h
done
```

In the latter example, I get no output (or errors for that matter). I've tried various escaping and quoting, but still no luck...I have a feeling it's something blatantly obvious that I am overlooking. Any pointers?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the script you posted, it may be the way you're using it. Run `bash -x /path/to/script` and look at what it's doing.

Comment: Even if it worked, you'd not usually do it that way. If you need to ssh to server1 and server 2 via bastion1, you'd make a connection to bastion1 once, then all others from there; not a new connection to bastion1 for every server. Also, there are existing solutions for monitoring servers, like munin.

Comment: why `ssh bastion1 ssh ${s} df -h` ?  just use `ssh ${s} df -h`

Comment: Thanks for the comments, it's necessary to hit the bastion host for remote access. There is no VPN, the bastion host has a public IP and from there I can jump to internal hosts. I am unaware of a method that would allow me to open a session and interact with that session remotely (certainly open to suggestions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two Method

Method 1:

```
Groups="server1 server2"
echo $Groups | xargs -n1 |  xargs  -I'{}' echo ssh '{}' df
```

Note:- if output is fine of above command then just remove `echo` in last then it will run commands on remote servers. do not use variable in CAPS because it's use for environment variable

Method 2:

You can refer below script

```
#!/bin/bash
# ssh password less login is required

# mention below remote server seperated by space

remote_srv=( 127.0.0.1 127.0.0.2 127.0.0.3 )

do_ssh() {
    ssh $s "$@"
    echo -e
}

header() {
    echo "#==================={$@}==========================#"
}

n=${#remote_srv[@]} # number of ip's in array

for (( i=0;i<$n;i++)); do
            echo -e
            echo "$(tput bold)$(tput setaf 2)* Connected Server: ${remote_srv[$i]}  @@ $(date) @@"
            echo "* Fetching info...$(tput sgr 0)"
            s=${remote_srv[$i]}

            header "Memory Usage"
            do_ssh free -m

            header "Disk Usage"
            do_ssh df -h
done

## EOF
```

Comment: Thank you @Rahul!

The all caps variable is a tip I didn't know. Also both functions and array in BASH were new to me. This worked, I ended putting the script on the bastion host and then I just call it remotely. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

UNIX has a better solution for you, you don't need to ssh and run df or du or etc ....

you can use `tmux command` on server and close sessions, But you didn't close your programs if you open via `tmux`.`tmux` works such as screen command but very very complex and useful.